# Using Flyway Teams Doesn't Seem to Work With CLI

Tags: flyway

I am trying to use the Flyway trial period for teams, but I can't seem to use it with any of the newer CLIs.

I've been able to use it with the enterprise-specific version from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/flywaydb/enterprise/flyway-commandline/8.5.9/), but I can't use it with any of the newer versions that are supposed to contain both community and teams code. I've tried both 9.9 (latest) and 9.2.

The license key is set in my conf file and I'm specifying the edition both through environment variables and flags, but it doesn't seem to pick it up.

I should also note that besides the batch and license key configuration settings, this validate works just fine with all three versions using community.

Command:

```
FLYWAY_EDITION=teams
$FLYWAY_PATH/flyway -teams -X validate -defaultSchema=$default_schema -url="$JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING" -configFiles=$CONF_FILE -placeholders.segment=${{ parameters.segment }}
```

Result:

```
DEBUG: Loading config file: /azp/_work/1/s/flyway-9.9.0/conf/flyway.conf
DEBUG: Unable to load config file: /root/flyway.conf
DEBUG: Unable to load config file: /azp/_work/1/s/infra/flyway/flyway.conf
DEBUG: Loading config file: /azp/_work/1/s/infra/flyway/./dev.conf
DEBUG: Using configuration:
DEBUG: flyway.baselineDescription -> Base Migration
DEBUG: flyway.baselineOnMigrate -> true
DEBUG: flyway.baselineVersion -> 0.0
DEBUG: flyway.batch -> true
DEBUG: flyway.cleanDisabled -> false
DEBUG: flyway.configFiles -> ./dev.conf
DEBUG: flyway.defaultSchema -> METADATA
DEBUG: flyway.ignoreMigrationPatterns -> *:pending
DEBUG: flyway.jarDirs -> /azp/_work/1/s/flyway-9.9.0/jars
DEBUG: flyway.jdbcProperties.authenticator -> snowflake_jwt
DEBUG: flyway.jdbcProperties.schema -> METADATA
DEBUG: flyway.jdbcProperties.tracing -> FINEST
DEBUG: flyway.jdbcProperties.user -> *****
DEBUG: flyway.licenseKey -> FL****************
DEBUG: flyway.locations -> filesystem:sql
DEBUG: flyway.placeholders.environment -> dev
DEBUG: flyway.placeholders.segment -> ***
DEBUG: flyway.schemas -> METADATA
DEBUG: flyway.url -> jdbc:snowflake://aza98716.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/?(...)
DEBUG: flyway.user -> ******
ERROR: Unexpected error
org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayTeamsUpgradeRequiredException: Flyway Teams Edition upgrade required: batch is not supported by Flyway Community Edition
Try Flyway Teams Edition for free: https://rd.gt/2VzHpkY
    at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.setBatch(ClassicConfiguration.java:1005)
    at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.configure(ClassicConfiguration.java:1615)
    at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.configuration(FluentConfiguration.java:943)
    at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.getLegacyConfiguration(Main.java:281)
    at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:122)
```

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `8.5.10` onwards, Flyway Teams was moved into a separate package so those features can't be used in the Community version anymore.

You have to download the Teams version separately from https://download.red-gate.com/maven/release/org/flywaydb/enterprise/flyway-commandline/